# Rebus - Who am I?

Tags: rebus, movies

This is my first rebus, and I only mention that because I needed more characters.

```
0
false
1 = 2
```

Who am I?

**Hint:**

> The rebus is a quote from a movie; the answer is the character that said it.

**Hint 2:**

> Each of the 3 statements corresponds to a statement in the quote, and they are all different.

Comment: Your evil twin, FFF!

Comment: ^^ I want this as an answer, so I can upvote it, more.  Hahaha

Comment: *Notices @fffred down in the comments, below.*  Found him!

Comment: The quote might be "Wrong, wrong, wrong!".

Comment: @Gamow- it seems many people are assuming the 3 statements are the same. I added another hint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer seems to be

> Luke Skywalker

Why?

> No!  That's not True!  That's Impossible!!
>
>  (Because I don't want to remove it) [Noooooooooooo](http://www.nooooooooooooooo.com/)

Comment: I like how you distinguish the first one from the last one :P

Comment: You should check that quote...

Comment: Honestly, I didn't expect someone to get the quote wrong and still get it right. :)

Comment: @TTT LoL - too funny

Answer (score 6):

You could be:

> A stack of lies.

Comment: That isn't it, but it's certainly the best answer thus far. :D

Comment: That ain't no lie :)

Answer (score 4):

I wonder if the answer is:

> True Lies

Reason:

> All three of the statements/expressions can have something to do with logical correctness.  A false boolean statement could easily be referred to as a True Lie.

Comment: That's not it, but it's a good match for the last statement.

Comment: And btw, ultimately the answer is a character, not a movie title.

Comment: ...not a phrase?

Comment: The rebus is a phrase. The answer is a character.

Comment: Oh, by character you mean the character in the movie? I was thinking about unicode and stuff.

Comment: @Gendarme - correct.

Comment: @TTT Hold on - the rebus is a phrase, but the answer is a character? Does that mean the answer is a character that says the phrase?

Comment: @question_asker - that's right. I just clarified the hint.

Comment: @TTT Thanks - that's what I figured you meant, I just wanted to make sure

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are

> Hitler

Similar to another answer here,

> The rebus gives three false statements, equating to "no", or, in German, "nein". The movie *[Downfall](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0363163/)* famously (thanks to the internet, mostly) features an angry Hitler pounding his desk and shouting *"Nein! Nein! Nein!"*

Comment: Nope. Good try, but IMO the phrase fits much better than that.

Comment: @TTT I had some doubts, but I enjoyed riding the wave of that other answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a stretch, but how about

> [C3P0](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/C-3PO)?

It's written in

> the **C** programming language

and has

> 3 **P**ropositions all equivalent to 0.

Comment: That is a stretch. :D

Comment: And a double equal sign == would be necessary

Comment: And some semicolons.

Comment: And only C++ has `false` as a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

> Chris Allen

Explaination:

> The picture gives three false statements. The word "no" can be associated with falsehood. In German, the word for "no" is "nein", or "9". Because they are three statements, we have "Triple 9". Chris Allen is a character from the movie [Triple 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_9).